# Density of PA degrees

Tags: logic, computability

**As suggested by Carl Mummert, I will ask a separate question (this question was posted but then deleted).** 
The following letters $a, b, e,\ldots$ denote Turing degrees. We say $a\gg b$ if there exists a complete extension of degree a to the Peano Arithmetic augmented with axioms $\dot{n}\in \dot{B}$ whenever $n\in B$, and $\dot{n}\not \in \dot{B}$ whenever $n\not\in B$, where $\dot{n}$ are constant symbols for $n\in \omega$ and $B$ is any given set of degree b. Now in 
**Volume 90, Pages ii-viii, 1-1165 (1977) HANDBOOK OF MATHEMATICAL LOGIC, Degrees of Unsolvability: A Survey of Results, Pages 631-652 by Stephen G. Simpson, Theorem 6.5 i)**, it is claimed that if $a\gg b$ then there exists another degree $e$ such that $a\gg e\gg b$. There was no proof there. I am wondering how to prove this?

Comment: Just a side remark - although this sort of question is perfectly welcome on math.SE, it would also be welcome on MathOverflow. The current policy is that you need to pick one site or the other, but for some questions you will get a different perspective on each site.

Comment: @Carl: thanks, I was worried that this is not a research problem so it may be incongruent to post this on math overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first key fact is that for every degree $a$ there is a $a$-computable infinite tree $T_a \subseteq 2^{<\omega}$ such that an arbitrary degree $c$ is PA over $a$ if and only if $c$ computes a path through $T_a$, that is, an element of $[T_a]$. This fact is mentioned relatively often in the literature.

The second key fact is that we can iterate finding paths in a certain way. There is another $a$-computable infinite tree $\tilde{T}_a \subseteq 2^{<\omega}$ such that any path through $\tilde{T}_a$ is of the form $f \oplus g$ where $f \in [T_a]$ and $g \in [T_f]$. (In the language of Reverse Mathematics, we might say that we can combine two successive applications of weak König's lemma into a single application.) This is well known to experts in the field, but perhaps not directly emphasized in the literature.

To see how to construct $\tilde{T}_a$, first note that $T_a$ is uniformly computable from $a$, which means there is a computable relation $R \subseteq \omega \times 2^{< \omega} \times 2^{\omega}$ such that, for all $\sigma \in 2^{<\omega}$ and $f \in 2^{\omega}$,
$$
\sigma \in T_f \Leftrightarrow (\forall n) R(n, \sigma, f).
$$

Next define a class $A \subseteq 2^{\omega}$ as follows. Given $f \in 2^{\omega}$, write $f = f_0 \oplus f_1$. Then we put $f \in A$ if and only if $f_0 \in [T_a]$ and, for all $k$ and $n$, $R(n,f_1[k], f_0)$. This is a $\Pi^{0,a}_1$ definition of $A$, so there is an $a$-computable infinite tree $\tilde{T}_a$ such that $A = [\tilde{T}_a]$, and the definition of $A$ ensures that $\tilde{T}$ has the desired property.

Now, because $\tilde{T}_a$ is computable from $a$, and $b\gg a$, there is a path $h = f \oplus g \in [\tilde{T}_a]$ computable from $b$. Let $c$ be the degree of $f$. Then $c \gg a$, because $f \in T_a$, and $b \gg c$, because $b$ computes $g$, which is a path through $T_f$.

We can extend this construction farther to show that, if $a \ll b$, then there is an $f$ computable from $b$ such that, if $f = \oplus_{i \in \omega} f_i$, then $a = f_0$ and $f_{i} \ll f_{i+1}$ for all $i$. So $b$ uniformly computes an entire increasing sequence above $a$ separated by $\ll$. In fact, $b$ computes a countable coded $\omega$-model of $\mathsf{WKL}_0$ containing $a$ (which is the same as a Scott set containing $a$).

The method in the previous paragraph, in turn, is one way to show that every countable coded $\omega$-model of $\mathsf{WKL}_0$ contains, as a single real, another countable coded $\omega$-model of $\mathsf{WKL}_0$. This is one of the more amazing and remarkable results of the field.